# Are mosquito bites harmful or just annoying?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Mosquitoes seem to be especially prevalent around the river, where they like to fly up and bite me while I'm fishing. I get a dialogue pop-up that I was bitten and that it's itchy, but I've had several at this point, and so far, they don't seem to be as bad as bee stings (which you need medicine to treat). I was worried that they would potentially interrupt me while I was trying to reel in a fish, but the pop-up at least seems to come after the catch, so there's no *actual* interruption.

Are there any negative effects to mosquito bites, other than the (mildly) annoying popup? Is there any way to avoid getting bitten, or is this just something I'll have to deal with all summer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosquito bites aren't "harmful" as the game has no HP system and you cant die or anything like that.

However, as stated by Alex, it prevents you from catching them. Residents may also have a new dialogue with you. Getting bitten by one also attracts more of them (creating an annoying cycle of stings)

You can avoid mosquitos rather easily, they have a short 'aggro' range and you can hear them coming (high pitched buzzing). They are also very slow moving, so they are easy to catch (once you spot them that is).

In short, they are just annoying. They only appear Summer evenings, though, so be a bit more careful during this timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's just annoying.  Also you don't get to catch it.  Same with bee stings